# How to train a model using a an array of continuous values as a feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, time-series

Say I have a Dataframe whose columns are features that I want to feed to a random forest classifier. These features are signals that are sampled at different rates and each row represents the values outputted by the sensor every 30 seconds. Each feature column that has a list of values have cells that contain lists of the same lenght Say my table looks like this:

```
|Epoch (30 sec) | Nasal Airflow 25hz   | EEG 200hz              | Target (0,1,2) |
| --------      | --------------       |--------------          |----- |
| 1             | [12,3,4,5,6...43]    | [6,9,8,5...,69]        | 1    |
| 2             | [15,45,8,4,9...89]   |[7,9.6,8.5,9...,89]     | 2    |
| 3             | [18,5,88,400,2...88] |[8,10.15,9.8,9.5...,45] | 0    |
```

All lists under the Nasal Airflow column has 750 numbers and all lists under the EEG column has 6000 numbers. The target column here is the value I want to predict.

I tried training a random forest classifier with the similar kind of data and it did not work. The error I got was

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I understand that I could apply some statistical methods like finding the mean, mode, median of each arrays but I feel like I'm losing a lot of data. Are there classifier models that can handle data like this?

Comment: Just to extra certain: Are the lengths of `Nasal Airflow` and `EEG` consistent (e.g. does *every* list in the `Nasal Airflow` column contain exactly 750 numbers)? If that's the case: you can flatten eachrows into length-6750 feature vectors.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Yes that is correct. Every list in each column have the same lengths as every other lists in their respective columns. I though about your suggestion but in my actual dataset I have 4 additional columns with each cell containing a list of 6000, 6000, 375, and 375 numbers, respectively. so with your method, I'd have 19500 feature columns which seems too large  and might cause performance issues considering my data set has close to 1000 rows?

Comment: If you're set on using random forest: there's no way around the 19500 vector (but it may not be the end of the world, DNA is millions of times larger and similar techniques are applied). If you can replace the problem with a time series prediction problem, there may be a separate set of methods that are more appropriate.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I think treating this as a time series problem works right? Because these signals are taken with respect to time and that goes for the target variable as well. Do you know any algorithms that I could use for this?

Comment: *Maybe*. I don't know enough about your problem setting and opinion questions are off-topic. [`sktime`](https://www.sktime.org/en/v0.8.0/index.html), [`tslearn`](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and [`pyts`](https://pyts.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) are three libraries that assist with time-series classification, you might work through some examples and see if they're doing something similar to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

(Turning comments into an answer)

If columns contain lists of equal length:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_file = StringIO("""airflow|eeg|target
[12,3,4,5,6,43]|[6,9,8,5,69]|0
[15,4,8,4,9,89]|[7,9,8,9,89]|1
[18,5,5,7,2,88]|[8,8,9,9,45]|0
""")

df = pd.read_csv(
    data_file,
    delimiter="|",
    converters={
        "airflow": lambda x: x.strip("[]").split(","),
        "eeg": lambda x: x.strip("[]").split(","),
    },
)
```

```
                airflow               eeg  target
0  [12, 3, 4, 5, 6, 43]  [6, 9, 8, 5, 69]       0
1  [15, 4, 8, 4, 9, 89]  [7, 9, 8, 9, 89]       1
2  [18, 5, 5, 7, 2, 88]  [8, 8, 9, 9, 45]       0
```

Then the *easiest* option is turn each list into columns representing "airflow at t1, t2, t3, etc."

```py
df[[f"af{i}" for i in range(len(df.airflow[0]))]] = df.airflow.apply(pd.Series)
df[[f"eeg{i}" for i in range(len(df.eeg[0]))]] = df.eeg.apply(pd.Series)
df.drop(["airflow", "eeg"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

```
   target af0 af1 af2 af3 af4 af5 eeg0 eeg1 eeg2 eeg3 eeg4
0       0  12   3   4   5   6  43    6    9    8    5   69
1       1  15   4   8   4   9  89    7    9    8    9   89
2       0  18   5   5   7   2  88    8    8    9    9   45
```

Which then can be used for model fitting. If the lists expand into a large number of features (e.g. 19,500), then [feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) approaches might be worth exploring. If there is a time-series component, non-linear models (like trees) can fit models of the form "*target is influenced by the airflow and eeg at t12*"—but other methods for time-series classification exist.

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = df.drop(["target"], axis=1)
y = df["target"]

clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried other implementations, but I'll try this soon.